# rails checking the existence of child objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails 4 app. User has_one profile. When sby registers he/she is already a user, but he/she will have only profile after submitting profile form.

On my users page I would like to display all the users that have profile.

There are a few ways to display users with existing profile but I don't know which one is the preferred.

1. Query in controller: loading only users w/ profiles

   ```
   @users = User.joins(:profile).includes(:profile)......
   ```
2. If `profile.present?` in view

   ```
   @users = User.includes(:profile).......


   <% if user.profile.present? %>
     <%= user.profile.first_name %>
     ...........
   ```
3. Maybe there is an even better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you go the other way? Load all the profiles, and it is sure that each profile would belong to a single user, so following code will do the job without any conditional line:

In controller:

```
@profiles = Profile.all
```

In view:

```
@profiles.each do |profile|
  profile.user # it would give you the user, whom it belongs to
end
```

To avoid `n+1` queries, you can use `Profile.includes(:user).all` in order to pre-load all the users.

Comment: You are totally right in this case. It's easy since it's 1-1 relationship.  But there are other cases when you can't use this one. Let's say you have to join another table as well that belongs to user. Which one would you choose from the first 2 options?

Comment: Can you please elaborate this thing in another question, and I'd answer it there.

Comment: Sure, but I have to wait a bit.